# Center Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a column inside a ListTile like this:

```
return ListTile(
    //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
    leading: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                    right: BorderSide(
              width: 1.0,
            ))),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello'),
              ],
            ),
              )
            ]),

...more code
}
```

Shouldn't this center the container vertically? I am doing something similar with a column and space around in the title section and it works fine.

Comment: It seems that `ListTile` has its own restraints. Maybe it'd be better to create custom widget instead of `ListTile`

Comment: I've tried your code and the Container is centered vertically within the Column. Is that not what you're asking for? You might have to show more code as there is no issue with the code you've shown so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try wrapping your column inside a container and giving it a fixed width like below:

```
leading: Container(
  width: 100,
  child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[]),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in a Center widget

```
ListTile(
//contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
    leading: Center(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                    right: BorderSide(
                      width: 1.0,
                    ))),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello'),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
    ),
    )
```