# How can I center a flutter_markdown Widget vertically?

Tags: flutter, dart, markdown, flutter-layout

As you can see in the Image there is a Container-widget (grey Box) and in it there's a Markdown-widget from the [flutter_markdown Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown).

I want that the Markdown-element is centered vertially in the Container ( where the yellow marker is) instead of where the Markdown is now ("Internet").

**EDIT:**
If the only possible solution is to add a fixed width I need to calculate it somehow, because it can be only one or many lines or a long text without line breaks. If there aren't any line breaks the flutter_markdown widget automatically wraps the text into the widget.

[How should it look like](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22666594/62426580-d5f75400-b6e6-11e9-86b1-aa35bbce04a0.png)

```dart
child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            color: _color
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: new Radius.circular(20.0),
              bottomLeft: new Radius.circular(20.0),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
                new BoxShadow(
                  color: _color,
                  offset: new Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                  blurRadius: 20.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: Scrollbar(
                child: Markdown(
                    imageDirectory: Store.storageDirectory,
                    data: _markdownText)),
          ),
        ),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center Column in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289550/center-column-in-flutter)

Comment: have you tried giving alignment to second Container?

Comment: yes, this changes nothing @A_Rush

Answer (score 1):

Markdown based on ListView and provide the same properties. Works for me:

```
Center(child: Markdown(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          data: store.subtitle))
```